# How to hide and show a certain object by Toggle

Tags: python

I want to make a toggle button that hides/shows cube objects.
but this seems not to be working.

Here is my code:

```
import bpy
if bpy.data.objects['Cube'].hide_set == True:
    bpy.data.objects['Cube'].hide_set(False)
else:
    bpy.data.objects['Cube'].hide_set(True)
```

[image]

Comment: You have to use `obj.hide_get()` to get the hidden state. Btw your script can be reduced to a single line : 
`bpy.data.objects['Cube'].hide_set(not bpy.data.objects['Cube'].hide_get())`

Comment: bpy.data.objects['Cube'].hide_set(not bpy.data.objects['Cube'].hide_get())

This is the answer I was looking for.
Thank you very much.
I think it will be of great help to what I do.